# Unable to implement sending tweet along with image to twitter in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter

I am working on asp.net mvc. I am trying to implement twitter compose tweet mechanism text along with image and send it as a tweet in twitter. I have followed the documentation provided by [twitter API 1.1](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update_with_media). I have followed the Twitterizer library to accomplish this one but it throws error to me like API version 1 is deprecated though i am using latest one and it is working for remaining endpoints except this one. so that i decided to make http request on my own

In my case i have textarea and file upload controls in my form like,

```
<form method="post" action="/Home/Upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>
<input type="file" name="file"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

After that in my action i have got the image selected by the user and text he entered into my action. I have convert the HttpPostedPostedFileBase into byte[] like,

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload(FormCollection coll, HttpPostedFileBase upfile)
        {

            byte[] data;
            using (Stream inputStream = upfile.InputStream)
            {
                MemoryStream memoryStream = inputStream as MemoryStream;
                if (memoryStream == null)
                {
                    memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                    inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                }
                data = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }

            HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json") as HttpWebRequest;
            OAuthBase oauth = new OAuthBase();
            string nonce = oauth.GenerateNonce();
            string timeStamp = oauth.GenerateTimeStamp();
            string normalizedUrl;
            string normalizedRequestParameters;
            string sig = oauth.GenerateSignature
            (new System.Uri("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json"), consumerKey, consumerSecret, userinfo.AuthToken,
            userinfo.PayUserId, "POST", timeStamp, nonce,
            OAuthBase.SignatureTypes.HMACSHA1, out normalizedUrl,
            out normalizedRequestParameters);
            string header = string.Format(@"OAuth oauth_consumer_key=""{0}"",oauth_signature_method=""{1}"",oauth_timestamp=""{2}"",oauth_nonce=""{3}"",oauth_version=""{4}"",oauth_token=""{5}"",oauth_signature=""{6}""",
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(consumerKey), HttpUtility.UrlEncode("HMAC-SHA1"), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(timeStamp), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(nonce), HttpUtility.UrlEncode("1.0"), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(userinfo.AuthToken), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(sig));
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", header);
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            ((HttpWebRequest)webRequest).UserAgent = ".NET Framework Example Client";
            Dictionary<string, object> fieldsToInclude = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            fieldsToInclude.Add("status", coll["new_message"]);
            fieldsToInclude.Add("media[]", data);
            string boundary = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "");
            string dataBoundary = "--------------------r4nd0m";
            string contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + dataBoundary;
            byte[] mydata = GetMultipartFormData(fieldsToInclude, contentType);
            webRequest.ContentLength = mydata.Length;
            webRequest.ContentType = contentType;
            using (Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                if (mydata != null)
                {
                    requestStream.Write(mydata, 0, mydata.Length);
                }
            }
            using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
                string retVal = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }        

            return View();
        }
```

Here i have written a method for preparing mutipart formdata structure for both image and text data like,

```
private byte[] GetMultipartFormData(Dictionary<string, object> fieldsToInclude, string boundary)
        {
            Stream formDataStream = new MemoryStream();
            Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;          

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in fieldsToInclude)
            {
                if (kvp.Value.GetType() == typeof(byte[]))
                {   //assume this to be a byte stream
                    byte[] data = (byte[])kvp.Value;

                    string header = string.Format("--{0}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{1}\"; filename=\"{2}\";\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n",
                        boundary,
                        kvp.Key,
                        kvp.Key);

                    byte[] headerBytes = encoding.GetBytes(header);

                    formDataStream.Write(headerBytes, 0, headerBytes.Length);
                    formDataStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);


                }
                else
                {   //this is normal text data
                    string header = string.Format("--{0}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{1}\"\r\n\r\n{2}\r\n",
                        boundary,
                        kvp.Key,
                        kvp.Value);

                    byte[] headerBytes = encoding.GetBytes(header);

                    formDataStream.Write(headerBytes, 0, headerBytes.Length);
                }
            }

            string footer = string.Format("\r\n--{0}--\r\n", boundary);
            formDataStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes(footer), 0, footer.Length);
            formDataStream.Position = 0;
            byte[] returndata = new byte[formDataStream.Length];

            formDataStream.Read(returndata, 0, returndata.Length);
            formDataStream.Close();

            return returndata;
        }
```

This is the way i am following to make http request to upload image to twitter(a.k.a upload with media). But i am getting error **500 Internal server error**. Please guide me if i went wrong in my procedure.

Comment: Is there any additional information to support your 500 error, such as a stacktrace?  Do you have customErrors turned off for debugging?

Comment: @Kyle B.  this is the stack trace and some times it throws 500 and some time 403 forbidden it throws.  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at MyProject.Controllers.AccountController.Upload(FormCollection coll, HttpPostedFileBase upfile)   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)

Answer (score 1):

I am the developer of Tweetinvi.
Uploading is as simple as this :

```
var imageBinary = File.ReadAllBytes("path");
var media = Upload.UploadImage(imageBinary);

var tweet = Tweet.PublishTweet("hello", new PublishTweetOptionalParameters
{
    Medias = { media }
});
```

I think this can save you a lot of time.

Tweetinvi documentation for upload : https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Upload

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in LINQ to Twitter, using the TweetWithMedia method, like this:

```
static void TweetWithMediaDemo(TwitterContext twitterCtx)
{
    string status = "Testing TweetWithMedia #Linq2Twitter " + DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    const bool possiblySensitive = false;
    const decimal latitude = StatusExtensions.NoCoordinate; //37.78215m;
    const decimal longitude = StatusExtensions.NoCoordinate; // -122.40060m;
    const bool displayCoordinates = false;

    const string replaceThisWithYourImageLocation = @"..\..\images\200xColor_2.png";

    var mediaItems =
        new List<Media>
        {
            new Media
            {
                Data = Utilities.GetFileBytes(replaceThisWithYourImageLocation),
                FileName = "200xColor_2.png",
                ContentType = MediaContentType.Png
            }
        };

    Status tweet = twitterCtx.TweetWithMedia(
        status, possiblySensitive, latitude, longitude, 
        null, displayCoordinates, mediaItems, null);

    Console.WriteLine("Media item sent - Tweet Text: " + tweet.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At last i found the way i.e. the issue present in the Twitterizer class library. As we all know Twitter API deprecated Twitter API 1.0 so Twitterizer library updated all twitter api endpoints according to Twitter API 1.1 but it did not update update_status_media endpoint. so that I am unable to make use of it. I got Twitterizer2 library source code from github. I have checked it out for update_status_media endpoint method and fix that issue. Changes need to be done in

**Twitterizer2/Methods/Tweets/UpdateWithmediaCommand.cs file Line Number 87**
change the line **this.OptionalProperties.APIBaseAddress = "https://upload.twitter.com/1/";**
to **this.OptionalProperties.APIBaseAddress = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";** this line.
this works fine. Here I saw the lines from Twitter API 1.1 documention says,

**Important:** In API v1.1, you now use api.twitter.com as the domain instead of upload.twitter.com. We strongly recommend using SSL with this method.

Hope this information helps to all.

Answer (score 0):

We can share image with SendTweetWithMedia() method by passing image as stream. Inorder to send image as stream we need to convert it.

```
private void sharetwitter ()
{
          var oauth_consumer_key = "your API key";
          var oauth_consumer_secret = "Your API secret key";
          string token = "access token";
          string tokenSecret = "access token secret ";
          var post = db.Posts.Where(p => p.PostId ==id).FirstOrDefault();
          StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
          str.AppendLine(post.Title.Trim());
          str.AppendLine("learn .net a lot of helpful programming stuffs.");
          var service = new TweetSharp.TwitterService(oauth_consumer_key,oauth_consumer_secret);
          service.AuthenticateWith(token, tokenSecret);
          string url = "http://www.infinetsoft.com/Images/logoinfi.png";
          service.SendTweetWithMedia(new SendTweetWithMediaOptions
          {
               Status = str.ToString(),
               Images = new Dictionary<string, Stream> { { "infinetsoft", urltostream(url) } }
           });
         TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "tweeted success";
}
```

here i found the solution for more details http://www.infinetsoft.com/Post/How-to-share-image-to-twitter-post-using-asp-net-MVC/1236#.V0Lj1DV97cs